# Adding class to class path of sbt plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I am using an `sbt` plugin to do some style checks on my code: https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat. On one of my projects, let's call this my-app, I added the `sbt` plugin to the `plugins.sbt` file inside the project directory.

The tool runs fine and everything seems to work as expected. This plugin has a compiler flag that allows for custom inspections to be passed in.

I therefore created another project, `my-inspections`, in which I added a custom inspection using the same classes as the `sbt` plugin. I then added my-inspections as an unmanaged jar in my-app. I did so by adding the following line to my `plugins.sbt` file:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += {
  Attributed.blank(file("lib/my-inspections.jar"))
}
```

Now, when I try to use the custom inspection class I added in `my-inspections` and pass it to the provided compiler flag, I get an error saying it cannot find the class. I passed in the fully qualified class name of the custom inspection I added. The `sbt` plugin then does something like:

```
Class.forName(inspection).getConstructor().newInstance().asInstanceOf[Inspection]
```

which causes a `ClassNotFoundException`.

How can the `sbt` plugin successfully load the `Class` I created that has the custom inspection?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the classes in a jar file, try putting the jar file in `project/lib`. The `project` directory is an `sbt` build for your project; an sbt plugin belongs to the project build. The `lib` directory in `project` is where you should be able to put [unmanaged dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html) of the project.

Comment: Should I add anything in my `plugins.sbt` file? I had tried this method and modified the question to provide more detail. Simply adding the jar in `project/lib` does not work unfortunately :/